# Catching a custom exception

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

I am having an issue with my code. I have simplified it here:

```
public class SuperDuper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try{
            method();
        } catch(CustomException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught!");
        }
    }

    public static void method() throws Exception {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
}
```

where my custom exception is just:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {
    public CustomException() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomException(String text) {
        super(text);
    }
}
```

However it is returning the following error during compile time:

```
SuperDuper.java:6: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
method();
      ^
```

What is it that I did wrong? If I change the catch to Exception it works, otherwise it does not.

EDIT: I see this got reported as being a duplicate but the duplicates suggested by the site were not dealing with this issue.

Comment: `method()` declares that it can throw `Exception`, so where are you handling that while calling it? Handling `CustomException` won't work. Compiler only knows about `Exception` being thrown by method.

Comment: READ the duplicate link.  It explains the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare that `method() throws Exception`, but you are catching `CustomException`.  Change your method signature to `throws CustomException`.  Otherwise you'd need to catch Exception, not CustomException.

Comment: Downvoted because...?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it for sure was worth at the end of the day, as I upvoted it, just to smooth it out :)

Answer (score 2):

`method()` is declared as throwing `Exception`, so you need to catch `Exception`. You probably instead meant `method()` to look like

```
    public static void method() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
```